# Mocking the current time in sinon

Tags: javascript, testing, sinon, stub

I am writing integration tests for my application that uses connects to MongoDB. I write the entity creation time to DB and use `Date.now()` for that.
My application is time-sensitive and hence I want to mock the current time such that my tests always work.
I have tried examples shared on multiple other similar posts but not able to get a working solution for me.

I try adding

```
const date = new Date()
date.setHours(12)
sandbox.stub(Date, "now").callsFake(function() {return date.getTime()})
```

in my `beforeEach` method but it has no impact.

I also tried

```
const date = new Date()
date.setHours(12)

sinon.useFakeTimers({
    now: date,
    shouldAdvanceTime: true
})
```

But this throws my mongoose schema validation for a toss and throws

> Invalid schema configuration: `ClockDate` is not a valid type at path `createdDate`

What is the right way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usage of `useFakeTimers` was doing what it intended to do. However, mongoose type comparison was failing as it does type comparison by checking the names.
The solution turned out to add `ClockDate` as a known type in mongoose inside the sandbox.

Adding the following line in the `before` method worked.

```
import { SchemaTypes } from "mongoose"
SchemaTypes["ClockDate"] = SchemaTypes.Date
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to make a stub for `Date.now()`:

`main.ts`:

```js
export function main() {
  return Date.now();
}
```

`main.test.ts`:

```js
import { main } from "./main";
import sinon from "sinon";
import { expect } from "chai";

describe("59635513", () => {
  afterEach(() => {
    sinon.restore();
  });
  it("should pass", () => {
    const mDate = 1000 * 1000;
    const dateNowStub = sinon.stub(Date, "now").returns(mDate);
    const actual = main();
    expect(actual).to.be.eq(mDate);
    sinon.assert.calledOnce(dateNowStub);
  });
});
```

Unit test results with coverage report:

```sh
  59635513
    ✓ should pass


  1 passing (8ms)

--------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File          |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
--------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files     |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 main.test.ts |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 main.ts      |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
--------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
```

Source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/mocha-chai-sinon-codelab/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/59635513